# Additional lines in the plotting graph

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions

I tried to plot the following

```
P = 0.16;
a = 1;
k = -1;
d = 7;

T[r_] = 1/(12 Pi r (r^2 + a k)^2) ((48 Pi r^6 P)/(d - 2) + 
     3 (d - 3) k r^4 + 3 (d - 5) r^2 k^2 a + (d - 7) a^2 k^3) - t

l = FullSimplify[NSolve[T[r] == 0, r]];

G[r_] = ((r^(d - 1)*P)/(d - 
       1) + ((d - 2) (k^2 a^2 + 3 r^2 k a + 
         3 r^4) k r^(d - 7))/(48 Pi) - (r^(d - 
          7))/(48 Pi (r^2 + k a)^2) (r^4/(d - 2) + (2 k a r^2)/(d - 
          4) + (k^2 a^2)/(d - 6))*(48 Pi P r^6 + (d - 
          2) (3 k (d - 3) r^4 + 3 k^2 a (d - 5) r^2 + 
          a^2 k^3 (d - 7))));

Plot[G[r] /. l, {t, 0, 0.2}, PlotRange -> {-0.2, 0}, 
 PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

this is what I get

[image]

and this is what the graph should be (forget the yellow dashed, it needs another value of P, my concern is only the two blue)

[image]

in other words, my graph contains additional lines, can you please tell me what is the problem with my code, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equations have more solutions than the two you are apparently interested in:

```
l = NSolve[T[r] == 0, r];
Length[l]

(* Out: 5 *)
```

(In passing, note that `FullSimplify` wasn't really doing anything to your NSolve output and can be safely eliminated.)

The solutions reproducing the plot you showed are the 4th and 5th in that list:

```
Plot[
  G[r] /. l[[{4,5}]], 
  {t, 0, 0.2},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 0.18}, {-0.12, 0}},
  PlotStyle -> Blue
]
```

[image: plot containing two blue lines resembling those in OP]

---

If it helps, this is how I viewed each solution independently to find that out:

```
Plot[
  G[r] /. #, {t, 0, 0.2},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 0.18}, {-0.12, 0}}
]& /@ l
```

[image: list of 5 plots, one per solution]

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your answer

Comment: @mesterFriendالمميز I'm glad it helped!